# Как программно вызвать submit redux формы с валидацией?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

У меня есть обработчик по своей кнопке, в которой мне нужно получить значения формы, пройти их валидацию и если всё нормально отправить post запрос.

```
  onMyClick() {
    const {store} = this.context;
    const state = store.getState();
    let data = getFormValues('form-id')(state);  // получаем значения формы
    data.is_draft = true;
    let errors = validate(data);  //моя функция валидации
    this.handleFormSubmit(data);  // функция отправки данных на сервер
  }
```

Проблема в том, что если errors непустой, то надо как-то подсветить поля на форме. Это всё работает автоматически для кнопки типа , но как это сделать вручную? Какой метод redux формы нужно вызвать?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать генератор действия [submit](https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-submit-form-string-code-)

```
import { submit } from 'redux-form'

handleClick () {
  const { dispatch } = this.props
  dispatch(submit('remoteSubmit'))
}
```

Более подробный пример: https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/remotesubmit/

Comment: Вот такая ошибка падает если так делать: "You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop"

Comment: @kidar2 handleSubmit нужно передать в компонент формы через props.

Comment: Он и передаётся. 
Выяснил что надо ещё передавать сюда:
forma = reduxForm({
  form: 'bla',
  validate: validateArticleDlg,
  onSubmit: function() {}
})(forma);

тогда всё работает. 
А вообще API redux-form полное г.